# how to fetch all the 87 object in this api

Tags: javascript, axios

I am trying to make a get request with axios to return all 87 objects in this api: https://swapi.py4e.com/api/people/

If we choose to show one object we modify the url like that "https://swapi.py4e.com/api/people/2"
this returns the properties of the second object in the api so I thought if I try to make a simple for loop to fetch all 87 objects one by one:

```js
const fetchPosts = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    let n = 1;
    for (let i = 0; i < 88; i++) {
        n = n + i;
        const res = await axios.get('https://swapi.py4e.com/api/people/' + n);
        setPosts(res.data);
    }
    setLoading(false);
}
```

This code has weird behaviour of returning only 12 objects and when it stops it gives error that it actually stopped at 94th and that's not true because it actually returned only 12

the error:
[image]

Comment: I wouldn't recommend you this way to load the data in general, but if it's needed, in `'https://swapi.py4e.com/api/people/'+n` you are expecting `n` to be in the range from `0` to `87`? if yes, why are you doing `n = n + i`? it's expected that this gives a wrong number after some iterations, you need to set `i` instead of `n` directly: `'https://swapi.py4e.com/api/people/'+i`, do you need it to start from 1 ? you can set `(i+1)` instead of `i`, or start your loop from `1` not `0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending 87 requests to get 87 results from a paginated API is very inefficient.

You should also never hard-code ["magic numbers"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) like 87 in your code, especially when interacting with an API you don't control. If people get added to or removed from the list, your code will no longer work correctly.

Note that `/people/` provides a `next` field that gives you a link to the next page. You can therefore use an asynchronous `while` loop to get all the results in just 9 requests (10 results per page).

Something like the following — you can swap out native `fetch` for `axios` if required:

```js
;(async () => {
    let nextPage = 'https://swapi.py4e.com/api/people/'

    let people = []

    while (nextPage) {
        const res = await fetch(nextPage)

        const { next, results } = await res.json()

        nextPage = next

        people = [...people, ...results]
    }

    console.log(people.length)
    console.log(people)
})()
```

---

**Edit (in response to @Jose Marin's comment below):**

A more efficient result in terms of time to completion (but still with only 9 network requests) can be achieved with `Promise.all`, which sends the requests in parallel.

This approach doesn't use the API's inbuilt pagination feature, instead inferring the number of pages from `count` and `results.length`. This makes it somewhat less elegant and less easy to reason about - there are a lot of places where hard-to-notice bugs could creep in, which I've commented.

```js
const getPeople = async () => {
    const url = 'https://swapi.py4e.com/api/people/'
  
    const res = await fetch(url)

    const { count, results } = await res.json()
    
    // zero case must be handled separately
    // otherwise we end up dividing by 0
    if (count === 0) return []

    const pageLength = results.length

    const pages = [
        results, // first page
        ...await Promise.all([
            // -1 because first page already fetched
            ...new Array(Math.ceil(count / pageLength) - 1).keys()
        ]
            .map(async n => {
                // +1 because zero-indexed
                // +1 because first page already fetched
                const page = n + 2

                const res = await fetch(`${url}?page=${page}`)

                return (await res.json()).results
            }))
    ]

    return pages.flat()
}

getPeople().then(console.log)
```

Comment: Just curios and to learn and to debate... Is it inefficient because the number is too high? Imagine that we are only talking about 9 requests like in your example, and that you are aware of the 9 requests you need to fetch before hand... I would say your approach is more inefficient than fetching the 9 requests in parallel. Wouldn't you?

Comment: @JoseMarin I was thinking of efficiency in terms of network requests, because those would have a bigger impact in terms of quotas on rate-limited APIs, costs for paid APIs, etc. However, you're correct  in thinking it wouldn't be the most efficient in terms of time to completion. I've edited my answer with an alternative version that is optimized in both aspects.

Comment: You are right as well... it all depends in the context of the environment and what are you trying to minimize to be more efficient.

Comment: @JoseMarin Yep, there are always tradeoffs. The tradeoff for my `Promise.all` solution is easiness to reason about - I had to go back and fix a couple of bugs that you'd run into if the number of results was a round number like 90, or if there were zero results.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to do 87 fetch then you just need to use var "i". The way you are doing now you will get the following values

1,2,4,7,11,16,22....92

Calculated from the sum of n + i

0+1, 1+1, 2+2, 4+3, 7+4, 11+5, 16+6,.....92

Try this:

```
const fetchPosts = async () =>{
            setLoading(true);
            for(let i=1;i<88;i++){
            const res = await axios.get('https://swapi.py4e.com/api/people/'+i);
            setPosts(res.data);
            }
            setLoading(false);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your API to see if it allows you to load pages with configurable sizes. If it is necessary to load one by one, I recommend making a series of promises.

example:

```js
function fetchPosts() {
    const promises = [];

    for (let i = 1; i < 87 + 1; i++) {
        promises
        .push(
            fetch(`https://swapi.py4e.com/api/people/${i}`)
            .then(res => res.json())
        );
    }

    Promise.all(promises)
        .then((data) => {
            // Your logic
        })
        .catch((e) => {});
};

fetchPosts();
```